# What happened to the second bangle?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-marvels

When Kamala returns to Earth she is only wearing the bangle that her grandmother gave to her. In fact, we do not see the other bangle at all from this point.

Do we know what happened to it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Carol is shown wearing it when they are in Louisiana.

[image: Screenshot of Carol wearing the bangle while running to the small plane at the end]

Comment: Heh - both my wife and I missed that and we were looking for it. Thanks

Comment: Wait, why is Carol wearing it? Just as an accessory?

Comment: @Möoz probably better than leaving it on a dead planet for the next big bad to find